# How to update a column dynamically with an agent job depending on time

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, sql-update, sql-agent-job

I need to update a field depending on another record. I use SQL Server.
In my database there are two tables.

```
create table product(
    IDproduct int primary key,
    numberA int default 0,
    numberB int default 0)

create table production(
    IDproduct int primary key,
    start datetime not null,
    duration time(7) not null,
    columnName varchar(32) not null)
```

I need to increment the field numberA or numberB of product when its (start+duration)<=getdate(). In the columnName of production there is the name of column to update (numberA or numberB). Finally I delete the record in production.

This is my current code, but I only update the column numberA:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @ProducedProducts TABLE(
    IDproduct int
);

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN;

    DELETE FROM PRODUCTION
    OUTPUT deleted.IDproduction INTO @ProducedProducts
    WHERE DATEADD(second, 
              datepart(hour,duration) * 3600 + 
              datepart(minute,duration) * 60 + 
              datepart(second,duration),
              start) <= GETDATE();

    UPDATE PRODUCT
    SET numberA += 1
    WHERE IDproduct IN(
        SELECT pp.IDproduct
        FROM @ProducedProducts AS pp
    );

    COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    THROW;

END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple job agent in order to update each column. In this way you don't need to dynamic job.